# Is Sharepoint only for Microsoft Office files?

Tags: sync, network-shares, upload, onedrive

The OneDrive for Business indicates SharePoint, but mainly refers to MS Office files.  Can I upload files of other formats such as WPD, DWG etc., and be able to use them in OneDrive?

Comment: To clear something: are you trying to upload files into OneDrive or using such files from SharePoint? From what I've read, there doesn't seem to be a limit on the type of files OneDrive accepts (it also wouldn't make sense, as competitors also don't impose such limits). On the other hand, what david stated may be true if you run such files from SharePoint.

Comment: DWG xrefs can be a nightmare if you aren't careful, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload other file formats, including the two you list, but there are restrictions. OneDrive for Business uses SharePoint libraries to store files. So file types blocked by SharePoint will be blocked for OneDrive.

The specific files blocked depend on if you are using SharePoint Online or on premises. Here's a list of file types that are blocked by each:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-HA101907868.aspx